# C++ function to return comparator-generic map type based on parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I assume I can use template magic to accomplish this, but I'm not sure how?

```
std::map<int,int,std::less> forward_map;
std::map<int,int,std::greater> reverse_map;

?? choose(bool forward)
{
    return forward_map ? forward : reverse_map;
}
```

Comment: Please check your `return` statement, you are checking the wrong variable

Comment: a function must have a single return type

Comment: A function must have a fixed return type at compile time. It cannot change that during runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return different types from the same function. Use an *higher-order function* instead:

```
template <typename TF>
decltype(auto) choose(bool forward, TF&& f)
{
    return forward ? f(forward_map) : f(reverse_map);
}
```

Example:

```
choose(true,  [](auto& m){ /* `m` here is a `forward_map` */ });
choose(false, [](auto& m){ /* `m` here is a `reverse_map` */ });
```

Comment: @LukeAndreson: you're welcome. Don't forget to accept my answer if you feel like it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to use the ternary operator as the expression must return the same type on both sides of the `:`.  You also cannot have a function that returns different things on different paths unless they are co-variant which these are not.

Now what you can do is use a non type template and use a bool type and then specialize that template for true and false.  This will allows you to have different return types with the same function name.  Doing that would give you

```
template <bool forward> auto make_map();
template <> auto make_map<true>() { return std::map<int,int,std::less<int>>{}; }
template <> auto make_map<false>() { return std::map<int,int,std::greater<int>>{}; }
```

And you would use it like

```
int main()
{
    auto map = make_map<true>();
    auto reverse_map = make_map<false>();
}
```

The only issue with this is the template parameter must be known at compile time.